# NSMutableDictionary with key:string and value:<string, string>

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm a noob to objective-c and I'm trying to create a dictionary with

```
key:string and value:<string, string>.
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: BTW - use `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: My question was basically looking for a tuple class, I guess...

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You claim you want a dictionary with a string key and a string value. And that's what your code does (other than using the wrong method). So again, what is your question about dictionary? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: I said I want to create a dictionary with key:string and value:<string, string>.  The value should be a tuple of <string, string>

Comment: That's the confusion. Your "clarification" in your question and your code both show otherwise. You can use an array of strings for your values as one option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to create a dictionary is to use the `NSDictionary` class.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key0": @"val0",
                       @"key1": @"val1"};
```

There is also a mutable variation called `NSMutableDictionary` that you can append.

To access elements in your dictionary, you subscript like so

```
NSString *val = dict[@"key0"];
```

The dictionary can store any sort of `NSObject` subclass as values.

**EDIT:**

I missed the part where you want to store a "tuple". You can use an array to do this

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key0": @[@"val0", @"val1"],
                       @"key1": @[@"val2", @"val3"]};
```

**EDIT2**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{@"key0": @[@"val0", @"val1"],
                           @"key1": @[@"val2", @"val3"]} mutableCopy];

dict[@"key2"] = @[@"val10", @"val11"];
```

Comment: How would you do this with an NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You may create custom pair class

```
@interface Pair : NSObject 
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *first;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *second;
@end
```

Comment: Why would you create a subclass to store a pair of objects? NSDictionary would be the correct solution to make a dictionary

Comment: Person wants to store 2 values for one key, does not he?

Comment: Woops, I missed that part. Then why not an array?

Comment: Array could be used as well, but it depends on code logic. If you *always* have *exact 2* items it is easier to use pair.